# module not found xlsx

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, xlsx

I have a nodejs project docker build that was building just fine on Azure Pipeline. But about 10 days ago, the build output changed to have one additional line that I do not understand the cause of it. Its the line "+ xlsx@0.17.0" at the bottom (in bold in output below).

Nothing has changed in the code between when the output didn't have that additional line and now.

Nothing was changed in the docker file or build definition as well. In the package.json, I am referencing "xlsx: ^0.14.5". Even if I change that to just "xlsx: 0.14.5" the output log will contain "+ xlsx@0.17.0" which confuses me. Shouldn't it try to install exactly that version?

NOTE: The reason I ask is because when this docker image gets pushed to Amazon ECS, it throws "Module not found 'xlsx'" Error.

THank you for your help!

```
found 10 vulnerabilities (2 low, 4 moderate, 4 high)
  run `npm audit fix` to fix them, or `npm audit` for details

> nodemon@1.19.4 postinstall /srv/node_modules/nodemon
> node bin/postinstall || exit 0

Love nodemon? You can now support the project via the open collective:
 > https://opencollective.com/nodemon/donate

npm WARN pg-cursor@2.7.1 requires a peer of pg@^8 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN swagger-ui-express@4.1.6 requires a peer of express@>=4.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.3.2 (node_modules/jest-haste-map/node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules/fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"linux","arch":"x64"})

***+ xlsx@0.17.0***

added 663 packages from 361 contributors and updated 2 packages in 11.462s

39 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

fixed 1 of 10 vulnerabilities in 1394 scanned packages
  4 vulnerabilities required manual review and could not be updated
  4 package updates for 5 vulnerabilities involved breaking changes
  (use `npm audit fix --force` to install breaking changes; or refer to `npm audit` for steps to fix these manually)
Removing intermediate container 4c02dbafa75c
 ---> c010404a92cb
Step 9/30 : ADD . .
 ---> d1925852f28b
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment so I will ask here:

Are you adding the `package-lock.json` file to the docker image? You're probably not, that's why npm is installing a newer version of the package.

That may fix the error if it's currently working on your dev environment. If not, how are you importing the package?